# batch to combine files without header

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a batch file to combine multiple csv files into one larger file while removing the header line.

It works, but does not combine all of the csv files in the directory. For example, if I have 4 csv files, it will only combine the first two.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\TheFileDirectory"
setlocal
set first=1
>bigfile.csv. (
    for %%F in (*.csv) do (
        if defined first (
            type "%%F"
            set "first="
        ) else more +1 "%%F"
    )
)
```

Comment: You could try dumping output to `bigfile.new` then at the end of the loop `ren bigfile.new bigfile.csv`.  I'm wondering if maybe your `for` loop is including bigfile.csv in its collection and causing problems trying to append itself, to itself.

Comment: @rojo Great thought! Just gave it a shot and still having the issue.

Comment: Are your CSV files large?  I'm thinking there's a size limit for `more` of 64k, but I could be misremembering.  If your second csv file is over 64k, maybe that's what's causing your script to die (although I would've expected output to truncate the file and the loop to continue).  If all else fails, you can use a PowerShell snippet.  `powershell "$i=1; gci *.csv | %{ if ($i) { $i=0; gc $_ } else { gc $_ | select -skip 1 } }" > out & ren out out.csv` from the cmd console, or double the `%` in a .bat script.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach:

Do a FOR loop over all *.csv files

Do a FOR loop over all lines of the CSV file while skipping the first row

ECHO the line of the CSV file and redirect the output to the bigfile with >>